# hide menu when click anywhere in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I have a left menu and when I click it appears and there is a cross button with id `close-button` when I clicked on it, menu disappears, I need to close also when click anywhere except menu.
[site link](http://opcinfotech.com/demosite/shriharimilan/)

```
(function() {
    var bodyEl = document.body,
    content = document.querySelector( '.content-wrap' ),
    openbtn = document.getElementById( 'open-button' ),
    closebtn = document.getElementById( 'close-button' ),

    isOpen = false;


function init() {
    initEvents();
}

function initEvents() {
    openbtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );

    //bodyEl.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu ); //

    if( closebtn ) {
        closebtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
    }
    // close the menu element if the target it´s not the menu element or one of its descendants..
    /**content.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) {
        var target = ev.target;
        if( isOpen && target !== openbtn ) {
            toggleMenu();
        }
    } ); */
}

function toggleMenu() {
    if( isOpen ) {
        classie.remove( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
    }
    else {
        classie.add( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
    }
    isOpen = !isOpen;
}

init();

})();
```

Comment: can you create fiddle/plnkr ?

Comment: When the menu is open, `create an EventListener` the listens on click on all elements (body) and then test, if the click was inside the menu or not. Delete the `EventListener` when the menu closes.

Comment: it is usually done with a transparent `div` that takes the whole screen, on which you put a click event (with z-index as this div is behind your menu, but on top of the content). You have to hide the div when menu is closed, of course

Comment: Add a listener to the body at click and check the object that is clicked, if the object is not in the menu then close it.

Comment: i have edited and there are some commented code. but this one also not working.

Comment: @yomisimie i have added body listener also but not working and its effects the functionality also menu not visible its hides the menu autometically. you can check commented script

Answer (score 2):

You'd better go with something like this. Just give an id to the div which you want to hide and make a function like this.Call this function by adding `onclick` event on document.

```
document.onClick=myFunction(event) { 

if(event.target.id!="popupDiv_id" || event.target.id=="closeButton_Id")
{ 
    document.getElementById("popupDiv_id").style.display="none";
  }
}
```

Comment: display:none not working for me. you can check link of a current menu i have mention in question. when i clicked on menu button a class added to my body. only in need to remove when clicked on anywhere in body except menu opened. i tried to hide body class but not working.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correct you can use the `onblur="toggleMenu();"` to run the javascript function when the element looses focus. It is the opposite of the `onfocus()`event.

```
<div class="menu-element" onblur="toggleMenu();"/>
```

Can also add the eventlistner in the javascript:

```
    var x = document.getElementById("menu-wrap");
    x.addEventListener("blur", toggleMenu, true);
```

There is some examples of it here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

Answer (score 0):

code look like this

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
            // hide any open popovers when the anywhere else in the body is clicked
            if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.menu-element').has(e.target).length === 0 && $(this).is(":visible")) {
                var target=$("#popupDiv_id").hide();
            }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply bind a click event to the body to close the menu. Then use event.stopPropagation(); on click of the menu.